# Find corresponding indices between two vectors in R

Tags: r, vector, plot, ggplot2, match

I have a 10*10 p-value matrix as:

```
pvalue<- structure(c(NA, -0.096323162317276, 0.122216485440731, 0.096323162317276, 
0.225789770483971, 0.161574333906174, -0.0300362538546324, -0.096323162317276, 
0.161574333906174, -0.160538598895073, NA, NA, -0.127395153045654, 
-0.167788729071617, 0.253754556179047, -0.108751960098743, -0.428793430328369, 
0.167788729071617, -0.108751960098743, -0.393578499555588, NA, 
NA, NA, -0.0911444947123528, -0.214396715164185, -0.15432420372963, 
0.0248575899749994, 0.0911444947123528, -0.15432420372963, 0.151217013597488, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.25789749622345, -0.15432420372963, -0.497151792049408, 
0.211289510130882, -0.15432420372963, -0.424650490283966, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, -0.15432420372963, 0.0248575899749994, 0.0911444947123528, 
-0.15432420372963, 0.151217013597488, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
0.0300362538546324, 0.096323162317276, -0.161574333906174, 0.160538598895073, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.304505467414856, -0.262040436267853, 
-0.397721439599991, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.349041998386383, 
0.319005727767944, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -0.160538598895073, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), .Dim = c(10L, 10L))
```

Then I adjusted them:

```
FDR<- p.adjust(as.numeric(pvalue), method="BH", n=45)
qplot(-log(as.numeric(pvalue), 2), FDR, ylim=c(-0.1, 0.5))
```

The following plot is produced. Every FDR value has a corresponding pvalue.
[image: FDR vs. pvalue plot]

The question is that how can I achieve the x and y indexes of a dot (e.g. the circled dot) in both vectors of `FDR` and `pvalue` vectors. Thanks.

Comment: Well, if you plot the values as text, as in @CMichael 's answer, and then do a lookup `which(x==lookupvalue)` ; or you could order your data before plotting and just count! Here you've circled the 3rd-to-last element, so its x-index is `length(x)-2`

Comment: Concerning your comment on my answer - are you actually interested in a graphical workflow (you mention a very huge data set) or do you just want to identify the lowest value in a robust way?

Comment: CMichael, I need a more robust way as commented in your answer. Carl have added a comment for your answer (up) to sort the file that you have generated. Then use which. This is not a very straight solution but the only solution up to now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `locator` function :

After you plot your data, enter :

```
locator(1) # to know the coordinates of only one point, locator(k) for k points
```

then click with the mouse on the point and you can see the coordinates in R console.

For you red circled point, it gives :

```
> locator(1)
$x
[1] 3.460083

$y
[1] 0.1408836
```

Of course, you can assign the value in a variable :

```
mypoint<-locator(1)
```

**Update:**

To get the actual coordinates, you can use `identify` function :

```
rk_elt<-identify(-log(as.numeric(pvalue), 2),FDR,1:length(FDR),plot=F)
```

Then click on the point and stop the `identify` function.

Returning to the console, you'll get `x` with `(-log(as.numeric(pvalue), 2))[rk_elt]` and `y` with `FDR[rk_elt]`

For the red-circled point, it gives :

```
> (-log(as.numeric(pvalue), 2))[rk_elt]
[1] 3.375973
> FDR[rk_elt]
[1] 0.1398239
```

Comment: I'd add that, since `locator` won't give you the actual `x` and `y` values in the dataset, you'll probably want to find the closest match.

Comment: Thanks Cath, very interesting but as Carl commented not the actual values especially in very busy plots which has very overlapped dots.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, you're right. I added a version with `identify` instead of `locator` to have the real coordinates. Of course, this doesn't really solve the problem of overlapped dots but to solve this, I guess it is better to work directly on the vectors.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
dataTemp   <- data.frame(FDR)
dataTemp$x <- -log(as.numeric(pvalue), 2)

require(ggplot2)

g <- ggplot(dataTemp,aes(x=x,y=FDR))
g <- g + geom_point()
g <- g + geom_text(aes(x=x,y=FDR,label=paste(round(x,2),round(FDR,2))),size=4)
g <- g + ylim(-0.1,0.5)
g
```

[image]

EDIT: For your question on "I need a script way to for example find all pvalues that correspond to min(FDR) values" this is very simple:

```
min.FDRs <- dataTemp[dataTemp$FDR == min(dataTemp$FDR),]
```

This yields a filtered data.frame min.FDRs which only includes the points equal to minimum FDR.

Comment: I doubt it -- he asked for the index, not the value.

Comment: @CMichael, this is interesting answer, but my real plot is very huge and it is impossible to check the corresponding numbers visually. Then I need a script way to for example find all pvalues that correspond to min(FDR) values. Can u help on this?

Comment: Ah overlooked the index aspect and thought in coordinates. You could also label them by ID and then use a lookup on the ID but I guess @CathG's solution is more elegant and user-friendly.

Comment: Dear CMichael, since I have NA (upper section of the matrix is NA) then this final code returns NAs instead of min numbers.

Comment: OK Michael, zooming on x and y solved the problem of overlapped points. thanks